# Including bootstrap and js in php

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at this!

I took code directly from one of of my old fiddles https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/fs9u6mwe/1/ to display photos in a college galley site. However it only shows one. When i include bootstrap and the function in my php it doesn't seem to read it! Why could this be?

My php looks like this

```
<?php
echo "<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/bootstrap.js'></script>";
echo"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>";
include "scripts/show.php";
echo" <title>Gallery Display</title></head><body>";

echo "<header>";
echo "<h1>The Ultimate Gallery Compiler</h1>";
echo "<div id='menu'><a class='head' href='index.html'>Upload Photo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='head' href='gallery.html'>Browse Gallery</a></div>";
echo "</header>";
echo "<div id='content'>";
echo "<h2>Browse Gallery</h2>";
$subfolder = $_POST["category"];
if ($subfolder == "0"){
    echo("Please <a href='gallery.html'>go back</a> and select a category");
    echo "</div><br><br>";
    echo "<footer>";
    echo "<p class='foot'>&copy; Copyright 2015-2016 MMA2 Rachel Gallen, Ysabel Pheifer and Rebecca Merrigan.</p>"; 
    echo "</footer>";
    exit();
}
$countcontents = file_get_contents("categories.txt"); //read file to get count
$countarray = explode('*', $countcontents); //get count of each category into an array
$categories = array("fashion", "music", "sports", "technology", "animals", "health", "other");


//output title according to if the gallery has images in it or not
for($i=0; $i< count($countarray); $i++)
{
    if ($subfolder == $categories[$i]){
        if (intval($countarray[$i]) == 0) {
             echo "<h3>No images have been uploaded for the " .$subfolder. " category yet</h3>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h3>Here are the images for the " .$subfolder. " category</h3>"; 
            echo "<p>There are ".$countarray[$i]." photos in this category</p><br>";
        }
    }
}

$folder = "images/".$subfolder."/";

// Open the appropriate subfolder, and display its contents.
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php
// also referenced https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGLi4ykt__0
if ($dir = opendir($folder)) {
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $images[] = $file; 
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}

echo '<div id="slider">';
echo "<ul id='slides'>";
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<li class="slide"><img src="';
    echo $folder.$image;
    echo '" alt=""/></img></li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
echo '</div>';
echo "<p>&nbsp</p><a href='gallery.html'>Reselect</a>";

echo "</div>";
echo "<footer>
<p class='foot'>&copy; Copyright 2015-2016 MMA2 Rachel Gallen, Ysabel Pheifer and Rebecca Merrigan.</p> 
</footer>";
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

by the way the javascript is

```
//Reference https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/fs9u6mwe/1/

$(document).ready(function() {

  //INDEX IMAGES SLIDER
  $(function slider() {

    //configuration
    var width = 360;
    var speed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var current = 1;


    //cache DOM
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('#slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');


    setInterval(function() {
      //move image the defined width and speed to the left
      $slides.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width
      }, speed, function() {
        //count number of slides and loop back to first from last
        current++;
        if (current === $slide.length) {
          current = 1;

          $slides.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
      });
    }, pause);
  });
}

);
```

Comment: It has to do with `$subfolder = $_POST["category"];` - `Notice: Undefined index: category` - POST is failing and is relying on a form(?). Should probably be a GET but unsure where that is populated from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included jQuery in your pages, you are using jQuery in your script but it is not loaded at all.

A nice way to find these things out is using the developer bar by pressing F12 when using chrome, then at network you can see which files were loaded and in console if there were any javascript errors.

Comment: @RachelGallen Bootstrap uses jQuery, and you are using jQuery in your page.

Comment: If you also check your console log it clearly shows this: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery