# Take photo or Upload photo in HTML

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

Hi trying to create a website that will let the user upload or take photo from the camera, and what I'm trying to use is the **accept="image/*" capture** that i found in the internet.

Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Take Photo</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" capture>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload">
   </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

and here is my upload.php file

```
<?php 
$target_path = "filecheck/check/takephoto/img/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
   echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

The problem is that i'm getting this error

Warning: move_uploaded_file(takephoto/img/panda-010.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/filecheck/check/takephoto/upload.php on line 6

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpz3tKo0' to 'filecheck/check/takephoto/img/panda-010.jpg' in /home1/filecheck/check/takephoto/upload.php on line 6
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!

How can I get the image uploaded to img folder.
I'm new at this.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm

Comment: Are you sure the folder you're trying to move the file to has write permissions for your webserver user?

Comment: Also, it looks like it can't find the uploaded file. Be sure to check the $_FILES array for errors.

Comment: Look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374857/including-bootstrap-and-js-in-php.  I had a similar issue last year.

Comment: @yok2xDuran did you look at my question? and did it help you? if you are still stuck, please comment